# Find and save inside for loop in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, for-loop, find, save

I have my request having a array of contacts i have to fine whether the contact is in the database:

```
{
    "vishReqHeader": {
        "ClientId": "0",
        "AppId": "101",
        "ApiCode": "1007",
        "ReqNo": "123456789"
    },
    "vishReqBody": {
        "RegPhNo": "9880889660",
        "Cnt": "3",
        "Contacts": [{
                "PhNo": "9880889660",
                "Name": "Alex"
            },
            {
                "PhNo": "9538607847",
                "Name": "Cindy"
            },
            {
                "PhNo": "9886949651",
                "Name": "Rob"
            }
        ]

    },
    "vishReqTrailer": {
        "DeviceData": "lat=12.9677992|lng=77.596204|IMEI=1234567890|appVer=3.0.1|OS=ANDROID|SoftVer=6.0.1",
        "Authentication": "securitytoken"
    }
}
```

If present fetch the details and save the details by adding the fetched details.
If not just add the contact in the database, but the query is not working as expected

```
router.route('/uploadContacts')
    .post(function(req,res){
        var j;
        for( j = 0; j < req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts.length; j++) {
            ProfileDetails.findOne({ 'PhNo' :  req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts[j].PhNo} ,
                function(err, profileDetail) {
                    console.log("*************reqreq********************")

                    console.log(j)
                if(profileDetail && profileDetail.PhNo ){

                    console.log(req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts)

                    console.log("*************reqreq********************")
                    var contactsDetails = new contacts();
                    contactsDetails.PhNo=req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts[j].PhNo
                    contactsDetails.RegStatus=profileDetail.Reg_Status
                    contactsDetails.profileId=profileDetail.Profile_Id
                    contactsDetails.PhoneBookName=req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts[j].Name
                    contactsDetails.updatedByProfileId=req.body.vishReqHeader.AppId

                    contactsDetails.save(function(err,result){

                    })
                }

                });

        }
})
```

here in the code

If i do find it is displaying the find details properly , when i try to save the jth value in the for loop is always 3

Not sure of the async call that is passing through

please help me to  correct the   quire , every element in the contacts array  has to do find and save how i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to fire a query for each phone number

First get all of the phone numbers in an array.

```
var phoneNumberArray =req.vishReqBody.Contacts.map(function(contact){
    return contact.PhNo
})
```

Then use the following code:

```
ProfileDetails.findOne({ 'PhNo' : {$in:phoneNumberArray}})
```

To get the name of the matched contact from your request,

```
req.vishReqBody.Contacts.find(function(contact){
    return contact.PhNo == profileDetail.PhNo
})
```

Comment: hoo yes that works but how do i get the value for    contactsDetails.PhNo=req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts[j].PhNo
contactsDetails.PhoneBookName=req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts[j].Name which are part of the incomming request array

Comment: checkout the updated answer. the last statement will return the contact object from the request

Comment: can u please say what is this matchedContact

Comment: its the `profileDetail` from your code. The one that got matched and returned by the database. Updated my code